# Issues with Propel 2

Tags: php, oop, orm, propel

I'm currently testing Propel 2.
I know that they aren't fully stable jet.

My issue is, that I try to insert data into a table.
So far so good.

But I get this Exception:

http://pastebin.com/LH4Pw5jf

This is the code for inserting:

```
            $db = new CoreCountry();
            try{
                $db->setIdent($ident)
                   ->setIso2($iso2)
                   ->setIso3($iso3)
                   ->setTranslation($translation)
                   ->setId(null)
                   ->save();
```

An this is the table description:

```
CREATE TABLE core_country (
    id integer NOT NULL,
    ident character varying(64),
    iso2 character varying(2),
    iso3 character varying(3),
    translation text
);
CREATE SEQUENCE core_country_id_seq
    START WITH 1
    INCREMENT BY 1
    NO MINVALUE
    NO MAXVALUE
    CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE lab.core_country_id_seq OWNER TO postgres;
ALTER SEQUENCE core_country_id_seq OWNED BY core_country.id;
ALTER TABLE ONLY core_country ALTER COLUMN id SET DEFAULT nextval('core_country_id_seq'::regclass);
ALTER TABLE ONLY core_country ADD CONSTRAINT core_country_ident_key UNIQUE (ident);
ALTER TABLE ONLY core_country ADD CONSTRAINT core_country_iso2_key UNIQUE (iso2);
ALTER TABLE ONLY core_country ADD CONSTRAINT core_country_iso3_key UNIQUE (iso3);
ALTER TABLE ONLY core_country ADD CONSTRAINT core_country_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

I removed the not null statement, but it was readded automatically by the db.

I also inserted an empty string into the setId method, but that returned that you are not allowed to add anything to an autoincrement field.

Please help.

Comment: You should post an issue on the official Propel repository https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please always post your schema.xml so we're seeing your real table description.

The error says

```
FEHLER:  NULL-Wert in Spalte »id« verletzt Not-Null-Constraint
```

You have set `id` to `null` right before the `->save()` call. So it's pretty obvious that you shouldn't pass `null`, set a right value or make it auto-increment and drop the `->setId()` call.